# wrap long text of radiobutton in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am implementing radiobutton in my app, but if I have long text for single radiobutton it need to wrap itself but presently its appearing as single line. The code is as below

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
for (int i = 0; i < (model).getItemCount(); i++)
        {
            String optionLabelStr = (model).getItem(i);
            RadioButton button = new RadioButton(optionLabelStr);
            button.addActionListener(this);
            button.setOppositeSide(false);
            cont.addComponent(button);
            buttonGroup.add(button);
            }
```

I tried using textarea by setting UIID to Spanlabel, but when I select the text, it doesnt mark to radiobutton, but if I select radiobutton it works fine. So, if I work with textarea, I want radiobutton to get ticked even when text is selected.

Any help on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`RadioButton` derives from `Button` which derives from `Label`. They can't wrap. Wrapping text is a complex feature that would seriously impact performance and functionality if we introduced it for all components. However, this is easy to accomplish with lead components. In fact `SpanButton` is a lead component.

So you can do something like:

```
RadioButton button = new RadioButton();
TextArea textOfButton = new TextArea(optionLabelStr);
textOfButton.setEditable(false);
textOfButton.setUIID("RadioButton");
Container lead = BorderLayout.centerEastWest(button, textOfButton, null);
lead.setLeadComponent(button);
button.addActionListener(this);
buttonGroup.add(button);
cont.addComponent(lead);
```

What you are effectively doing here is wrapping the button with the text. Then making the text look like the text of the radio button should.

Finally you're defining the lead component. This means all clicks within `lead` will go to the radio button and it will handle all events and UI state changes. Creating something that looks/behaves like a single button.